# How to use MaxBy in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list that I would like to group into group and then for each group get the max value. For example, a list of actions of user, get the last action per user.

```
case class UserActions(userId: String, actionId: String, actionTime: java.sql.Timestamp) extends Ordered[UserActions] {
  def compare(that: UserActions) = this.actionTime.before(that.actionTime).compareTo(true)
}
val actions = List(UserActions("1","1",new java.sql.Timestamp(0L)),UserActions("1","1",new java.sql.Timestamp(1L)))
```

When I try the following groupBy:

```
actions.groupBy(_.userId)
```

I receive a Map

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[UserActions]] = Map(1 -> List(UserActions(1,1,1970-01-01 00:00:00.0), UserActions(1,1,1970-01-01 00:00:00.001))
```

Which is fine, but when I try to add the maxBy I get an error:

```
actions.groupBy(_.userId).maxBy(_._2)
<console>:13: error: diverging implicit expansion for type 
Ordering[List[UserActions]]
starting with method $conforms in object Predef
       actions.groupBy(_.userId).maxBy(_._2)
```

What should I change?

Thanks
Nir

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `Map` of `String` (userId) `-> List[UserActions]` and you want each list reduced to just its max element?

```
actions.groupBy(_.userId).mapValues(_.max)
//res0: Map[String,UserActions] = Map(1 -> UserActions(1,1,1969-12-31 16:00:00.0))
```

You don't need `maxBy()` because you've already added the information needed to order/compare different `UserActions` elements.

Likewise if you just want the max from the original list.

```
actions.max
```

You'd use `maxBy()` if you wanted the maximum as measured by some other parameter.

```
actions.maxBy(_.actionId.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `compare` method should be:

```
def compare(that: UserActions) = this.actionTime.compareTo(that.actionTime)
```

Then do `actions.groupBy(_.userId).mapValues(_.max)` as @jwvh shows.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group values by using userId. You can do it by using groupBy().

`actions.groupBy(_.userId)`

Then you can take only values from key value pairs.

`actions.groupBy(_.userId).values`

You have used maxBy(_._2). So, I think You want to get max by comparing second value. You can do it by using map().

`actions.groupBy(_.userId).values.map(_.maxBy(_._2))`

Comment: Doesn't work. `Error: value _2 is not a member of UserActions`

Comment: @jwvh Sir, but it works for me for a same case. May be I misunderstood the question.